# Hello , why does it return False for file exists() when im using relative path but return True when path is absolute? thanks

Tags: python, path, pathlib

```
import pathlib

home1 =pathlib.Path("/Users/sergii/Desktop/hello.txt")
print(f"home 1 is located {home1.cwd()}")  #home 1 is located /Users/sergii/Documents
print(f"home 1 exists {home1.exists()}")   #home 1 exists True
print(f"home 1 is a file {home1.is_file()}\n")


home2 = pathlib.Path("Desktop/hello.txt")
print(f"home 2 is located {home2.cwd()}")  #home 2 is located /Users/sergii/Documents
print(f"home 2 exists {home2.exists()}")   #home 2 exists False
print(f"home 2 is a file {home2.is_file()}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second example is resolving the relative path `Desktop/hello.txt` with respect to the current working directory, so it's checking if `/Users/sergii/Documents/Desktop/hello.txt` exists.